htop: why thread CPU% sum isn't equal to process CPU%?
In this htop output, we can see that the process /home/jxz/server is taking 183% CPU usage. However, when we sum the CPU% of each child (which are the threads), it doesn't add up to this value. Why?
    PID△USER   PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command                                                                                                                      
 619077 jxz    20   0 14.9G 2879M 62324 S  0.0 18.4  0:00.02 │  │  │  ├─ PtyProcess Reap
 619079 jxz    21   1  290M 47184 20608 S 183.  0.3 40:53.94 │  │  │  └─ /home/jxz/server
 619084 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │  │  │     ├─ bench
 619085 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │  │  │     ├─ default-executo
 619086 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │  │  │     ├─ resolver-execut
 619087 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.04 │  │  │     ├─ grpc_global_tim
 619088 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.7  0.3  0:47.56 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619089 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:47.50 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619090 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.9  0.3  0:46.55 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619091 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:46.45 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619092 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.9  0.3  0:46.62 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619093 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:47.97 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619094 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  4.6  0.3  0:48.33 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619095 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:45.64 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine   
 619096 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.9  0.3  0:47.85 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619097 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:47.51 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine                                                                                                  
 619098 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:46.33 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619099 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.9  0.3  0:45.13 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619100 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:47.65 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619101 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:46.46 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619102 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.3  0.3  0:47.65 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619103 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  3.9  0.3  0:47.59 │  │  │     ├─ event_engine
 619104 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.03 │  │  │     ├─ lifeguard
1111124 jxz    20   0  290M 47184 20608 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 │  │  │     └─ grpcpp_sync_ser
   5460 jxz    20   0 1708M  177M 29488 S  0.7  1.1  1:19.61 │  │  ├─ /usr/bin/Xwayland :1 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.2PA3L2 -listen 4 -l



What do you mean? Why would you expect them to sum to the total of another process? Each of these is a separate process.

No, I enabled "Display threads in a different color" in htop, each of the child is a thread. We cannot see it here, but the children are in green (threads) and the parent is in white (process)

Note how they each have a different process ID. The main process may have forked to create them, but that doesn't imply the main process isn't doing anything else. I can write a little program that calculates prime numbers in the background, while also forking 100 child processes that do nothing but sleep. That would look like what you show with the threads using very little CPU and the main process still using loads.

Does that mean that the main thread is taking 183% CPU usage? How is it even possible that a single thread uses more than 100% CPU usage?

Yep, looks that way. Let's wait and see if anyone posts an answer, I may be wrong, but that's how I read it.
